# Best practices for reporting events within iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to receive communication from my `iOS` app, reporting some events. For example, when a specific item is not found in the database, I would like to receive a notification so I can go ahead and check why the item is not there.

Now, I use `parse.com` as `backend`, one option would be to create a table and add all `reporting` over there. It just doesn't seem natural do have the `client` creating objects that have nothing to do with their user's experience. Another option would be to send emails, using `Sengrid` or similar to company staff, so they can fix the problem.

Anyways, my question is: What are the best practices for communicating events that happen in the app without user's knowledge? And of course, in a way (fast and clean) that will not interfere on user's experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is purely for crash and error management we use [crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com). It's very powerful. If not you can setup custom events in Google Analytics. Of you can extend the intent of crashlytics to do more for you.

Comment: Well thanks, but actually this is not for crashes. It is some database  problems, just like the example above, in case my database has relations to inexistent objects  I want the company to be notified so they can fix the relation.

Comment: You can still use the custom event of crashlytics or setup custom events in GA